# Compare two comma separated strings and get count of intersecting values

Tags: linq, string-comparison

What is the best code for comparing 2 comma separated strings and retrieving values that intersect? For instance lets say I have  string "a,b,c" and the target string "x,b,y", I need result saying there is 1 occurrence.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124216/what-is-the-shortest-code-to-compare-two-comma-separated-strings-for-a-match#) One way of doing this is

```
public static bool UserCanAccessThisPage(string userAccessGroups,
    string pageItemAccessGroups)
{
    return userAccessGroups.Split(',')
                           .Select(s => s.Trim())
                           .Contains(pageItemAccessGroups);
}
```

But this will only check the match but I do also need occurrences. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get intersection of two sequences:

```
var occurrences = 
    userAccessGroups.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim())
         .Intersect(pageItemAccessGroups.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()));
```

Checking if occurrences exist:

```
bool exist = occurrences.Any();
```

Getting occurrences count:

```
int count = occurrences.Count();
```

---

To make code more readable you can store groups in local variables:

```
 // this can be ordinal named method
 Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> parse = 
     csv => csv.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());

 var userGroups = parse(userAccessGroups);
 var pateItemGroups = parse(pageItemAccessGroups);
 var occurrences = userGroups.Intersect(pageItemGroups);
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for. Worked like charm. Thanks a lot